# Kendo with Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

How do I set the culture to English UK for kendo components in angular? For example, a numbertextbox currency defaults to $ but i want it to default to £. Any suggestions

Comment: kendo.culture("en-GB"); See http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/globalization/index

Comment: So i literally just embed that within my controller?